# Liquibase Hibernate Plugin Does Not Work

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

As described here (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/74) I'm having an issue getting the liquibase-hibernate extension to work properly. I think I have everything setup, but it seems like I keep running into weird problems. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I think I've followed all the instructions as provided.

I'm using liquibase 3.3.2, Hibernate 4.3.0.Final, java 1.7.0_71 and the liquibase-hibernate4-3.5.jar. My CLASSPATH environmental variable is empty, but some stuff gets added to it by the liquibase shell script. When I'm using normal liquibase commands interacting, and I remove the extension from $LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib/ directory without the extension it works just fine. I reran the commands with DEBUG output on to provide some more information.

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH


$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

$ liquibase --version
Liquibase Version: 3.3.2

$ liquibase diffChangeLog
//The below is the stuff liquibase is adding to my classpath
.:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/liquibase.jar:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/lib/liquibase-hibernate4-3.5.jar:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
WARNING 1/19/15 12:42 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 1/19/15 12:42 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 1/19/15 12:42 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateClassicDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:20 AM: liquibase: Connected to root@localhost@jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dirtylibs
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:20 AM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect)

SEVERE 1/19/15 10:20 AM: liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect)
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialec
t.MySQL5Dialect)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:69)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.createReferenceDatabaseFromCommandParams(Main.java:1169)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:936)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:175)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:239)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:143)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:50)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:191)
        ... 6 more
```

My liquibase.properties file

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dirtylibs
username=root
password=password
changeLogFile=changelog.xml
#referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
referenceUsername=root
referencePassword=password
```

If I uncomment my referenceDriver I get this. Is there something I'm missing here? I thought I had all the required dependencies, and I'm not sure if this is some manifestation of the earlier problem where the extension could not load stuff properly.

```
$ liquibase diffChangeLog
WARNING 1/19/15 12:49 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 1/19/15 12:49 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 1/19/15 12:49 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateClassicDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 1/19/15 12:49 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.snapshot.SequenceSnapshotGenerator as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.id.factory.IdentifierGeneratorFactory is not in the classpath
WARNING 1/19/15 12:49 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.snapshot.TableSnapshotGenerator as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.id.factory.IdentifierGeneratorFactory is not in the classpath
Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.hibernate.sql.Alias
SEVERE 1/19/15 10:22 AM: liquibase: org.hibernate.sql.Alias
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/sql/Alias
        at liquibase.ext.hibernate.snapshot.PrimaryKeySnapshotGenerator.<clinit>(PrimaryKeySnapshotGenerator.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.<init>(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:29)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getInstance(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:43)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotControl.addType(SnapshotControl.java:95)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotControl.setTypes(SnapshotControl.java:88)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotControl.<init>(SnapshotControl.java:25)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:185)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:140)
        at liquibase.command.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run(DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:51)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:8)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:121)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:936)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:175)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.sql.Alias
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 18 more
```

After adding the hibernate jar to the liquibase/lib folder (which is really wrong) the error turned into this. I tried reverting to an older version of the plugin (while downgrading liquibase as well), and it did not help.

```
$ liquibase --logLevel=DEBUG diffChangeLog
.:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/liquibase.jar:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/lib/liquibase-hibernate4-3.5.jar:/c/repos/ServeDirtyLibsInJava/liquibaseLib/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
WARNING 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry is not in the classpath
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Connected to root@localhost@jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dirtylibs
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
WARNING 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Unknown database: Hibernate
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Connected to null@hibernate:spring:com.companyname.dirtylibs.persistence.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Not adjusting the auto commit mode; it is already false
INFO 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Error getting default schema
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$QueryCallableStatementCallback.doInCallableStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:383)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:96)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:132)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:143)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:151)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:166)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:161)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getConnectionSchemaName(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:318)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getDefaultSchemaName(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:301)
        at liquibase.CatalogAndSchema.customize(CatalogAndSchema.java:132)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:116)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:190)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:140)
        at liquibase.command.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run(DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:51)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:8)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:121)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:936)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:175)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94)
DEBUG 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1421681927678 as b60efdd1567f2fd4e5407a8d157cb0b6
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.NullPointerException

SEVERE 1/19/15 10:38 AM: liquibase: java.lang.NullPointerException
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:123)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:936)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:175)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:13)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:121)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseCatalogNames(CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:82)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:41)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:60)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:163)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:55)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:37)
        at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:25)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:126)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:119)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:190)
        at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:140)
        at liquibase.command.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run(DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:51)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:8)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working by adding these jars to my classpath. This is super confusing and not well documented.
The process I went through was:

1. Download the source for the correct plugin project found here (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/releases) in my case it was liquibase-hibernate4-3.5.
2. Run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`. This dumps them into `/target/dependency/`. Copy all these jars and put them into your `LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib` directory.
3. I'm using gradle so I used a custom task to copy all my dependencies. If you're using maven you can use the same step from 2 on your own project to fetch all your depdenencies. I copied these libs from my output directory into the `LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib` directory.

   ```
   task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
       into "$buildDir/output/libs"
       from configurations.runtime
   }
   ```
4. I also put the correct `hibernate-liquibase-4.3.5.jar` into the `LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib` directory.

That gave me all the dependencies I needed for the plugin.

This is a big nasty ball of mess, but what can you do :(

Answer (score 8):

If you check the source code for this plugin, the following dependencies (all the spring dependencies) are marked as "provided" scope in the pom:

```
spring-test
spring-jdbc
spring-beans
spring-context
spring-orm
```

So the plugin will assume these have been provided on the classpath by your app, but this won't automatically happen in your maven build, as it will not run with the same classpath that your application will.

So, to fix, add the dependencies in your plugin, easier than doing the jar file shuffle:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

If you are keen, you can do a pull request on the github repo to remove the provided scopes from the pom, oh and probably this line too:

```
            <role>architect</role>
```

Comment: That's some good feedback. Never thought about looking at the building for the source pom. I have no idea why they mark all the spring stuff as provided.

Comment: And what if you want to use Liquibase in a project that is not based on Spring?

Answer (score 1):

The path I tried was a bit different with the accepted anwer.  I created a dev profile in my war's pom.xml (I am using maven) which does exactly the same with the default profile but including the Liquibase-hibernate dependency jar files under the war/WEB-INF/lib.  And then instead of using the liquibase command line provided, I use the liquibase.jar file directly with the classpath is my war file:

```
java -jar $LIQUIBASE/liquibase.jar --classpath=<WAR FILE HERE>  --defaultsFile=<yourpath>/liquibase.properties --logLevel=info
```

And then created a connvenience script which will build my project with that liquibase-hibernate profile then execute the diffChangeLog command.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I fixed it by removing the hbm2ddl-property in the hibernate.cfg.xml. Somehow the driver class cannot be read in the cfg.xml if this property is on. There is a part in the liquibase-hibernate wiki in git where it says "Why not to use HBM2DDL" but it does not really say to remove it from the cfg.xml.

Comment: There is already an answer that solves the issue. And it is by OP himself, so every aspect of the question has been solved.