# liquibase-hibernate shows all tables as "unexpected"

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28033654/3000316) steps to get liquibase-hibernate working. I hope I correctly understood the instructions in the [wiki](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki).

Our hibernate entities are declared in the file `applicationContext.xml`. We do not have a `hibernate.cfg.xml`. My liquibase properties are:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1234/MY_DATABASE
username=user
password=pass
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:somePackage?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

The thing is no matter what I enter as `somePackage`, liquibase shows *everything* (tables, columns, constraints) as "unexpected". Liquibase "finds" `somePackage` even if it does not exist.

```
liquibase diff
INFO 09.08.17 10:41: liquibase-hibernate: Reading hibernate configuration hibernate:spring:somePackage?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO 09.08.17 10:41: liquibase-hibernate: Found package somePackage
```

And the comparison result is like

```
Reference Database: null @ hibernate:spring:somePackage?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect (Default Schema: HIBERNATE)
Comparison Database: postgres @ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1234/MY_DATABASE (Default Schema: public)
Compared Schemas: HIBERNATE -> public
Product Name:
     Reference:   'Hibernate'
     Target: 'PostgreSQL'
Product Version:
     Reference:   '4.3.11.Final'
     Target: '9.5.4'
Missing Catalog(s): NONE
Unexpected Catalog(s): NONE
Changed Catalog(s):
     HIBERNATE
          name changed from 'HIBERNATE' to 'MY_DATABASE'
Missing Column(s): NONE
[...]
Unexpected Table(s):
    activityentity
    addressentity
    advertisemententity
    advertisementusageentity
    [...]
```

I really don't know what's going on or whether I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't. seems like this plugin is hopelessly broken.

Comment: Which version of Spring and eventually Spring Boot do you use? I'm upgrading to to Spring 5 with Boot 2.1.5 with liquibase-core@3.6.3 and liquibase-hibernate@3.7 and I have the same issue. If I find a solution will post again.

Comment: @DesislavKamenov Did you get this working before upgrading? If so what versions of liquibase-core and liquibase-hibernate were you using? Thanks!

Comment: I had a change of priorities and will get back to this task on Monday (05.Aug)

Comment: Finally ended up reverting to core@3.5.3 and hibernate-plugin@3.7 to make it work :( as core@3.6-3.7 wasn't working for me at all. There are core and plugin 3.8 which i haven't tested yet.